# Select number of completed trips by a plane

Tags: sql

I'm suppose to select number of trips completed by plane TU-134. I'm doing basic exersices on some website.

```
SELECT plane, COUNT(trip) as numberOfTrips FROM Pass_in_trip
INNER JOIN Trip WHERE plane = 'TU-134'
```

This prints

> plane TU-134 numberofTrips 128

But its still not correct why? I assume im not getting the completed trips?

Update with tables:
[image]

Comment: Your query has an INNER JOIN but I don't see an ON in it. Should there be an ON clause in this join?

Comment: What are the fields in `Pass_in_trip` and `Trip` tables, provide more details.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: the problem here is that your count functions counts every row because you did not indicate a partition which to group on. A quick fix of your query would be adding the `GROUP BY plane` clause at the end of your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your inner join statement and group data by plane so you can use count function.

[Inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

[Group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT 
   Plane = T.plane, 
   NumberOfTrips = COUNT(P.trip)  
FROM       Pass_in_trip P
INNER JOIN Trip         T ON P.Trip= T.Id
WHERE 
   T.plane = 'TU-134'
GROUP BY
   T.plane
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused of the namings of the attributes like T on P

Comment: @Snozye it is just alias for tables I use alias P for "Pass_in_trip" nad T for "Trip", you can remove it if you want query will work without them. Alias is nice to use if you have tables with long name for example it is easier to write LTB instead "LongTableName".

If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted answer.